# How to add a delegate with parameter values and without lambda expression

Tags: c#, events, architecture, delegates

I'm trying to find a way to add delegates with parameter values but without lambda expressions. I can't find a architecture which allows it - fitting to my needs. Look at following example:

```
public class MyDelegateClass
{
  public class ArgsHolder : EventArgs
  {
    public object[] data;
    public ArgsHolder(params object[] data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
  }

  public event EventHandler handler;
  public void Execute()
  {
        ArgsHolder holder = new ArgsHolder(5, 3); // this is the problem
        handler?.Invoke(this, holder);
  }
}

public class OutsideClass
{ 
  public void Start()
  {
    MyDelegateClass del = new MyDelegateClass();
    del.handler += new EventHandler(EventMethod);
    del.Execute();
    del.handler -= new EventHandler(EventMethod);
  }

  private void EventMethod(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    ArgsHolder holder = (ArgsHolder)args;
    print(args.data[0] + " " + args.data[1]
  }
}
```

The problem is, that the MyDelegateClass sets the values, which would be avoidable with a lambda expression like this:

```
public class OutsideClass
{ 
  public void Start()
  {
    MyDelegateClass del = new MyDelegateClass();
    ArgsHolder holder = new ArgsHolder(5,3);
    del.handler += (sender,args) => EventMethod(this, holder);
    del.Execute();
    del.handler -= (sender,args) => EventMethod(this, holder); // this is now the problem
  }

  private void EventMethod(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    ArgsHolder holder = (ArgsHolder)args;
    print(args.data[0] + " " + args.data[1]
  }
}
```

This would be working, but now I can't remove the event which is necessary, because the subscriber objects are dynamic in my project. I hope I was precise enough in elaborating the problem at hand :)

Comment: Just save delegate to variable, then sub/unsub.

Comment: If it isn't clear what eocron wrote, `EventHandler ea = (sender,args) => EventMethod(this, holder); del.handler += ea; del.Execute(); del.handler -= ea;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removal of subscribing handlers is based on reference comparison, so as long as you create one delegate from a lambda expression and store it, you can remove it:

```
public void Start()
{
  MyDelegateClass del = new MyDelegateClass();
  ArgsHolder holder = new ArgsHolder(5,3);
  
  EventHandler eventHandler = (sender,args) => EventMethod(this, holder);

  del.handler += eventHandler;
  del.Execute();
  del.handler -= eventHandler;
}
```

In a more complicated scenario where the subscribe action happens in a different place than unsubscribe you'd store the reference to the handler in a field.